# Angular / Kendo - popup element is attached to very end of DOM

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

if I open kendo dropdown or anything from kendo which has something like popup window, everytime it is attached to very end of DOM, which is problem when I want to restyle it ( because its same component used for dropdown, combobox, autocomplete, dropdownbutton )... is there any way how to attach this popup to component itself in DOM ? I have heard its possible but can't find any solution.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to change the way the popup are attached to the DOM.
However, you can still style them the way you want, because each popup has a different CSS class name.

For example:

- `k-calendar-container` for `kendo.ui.DatePicker`
- `k-list-container` for `kendo.ui.DropDownList` and `kendo.ui.AutoComplete`

I've created an exemple: https://jsfiddle.net/Metoule/1kfgct3x/

Also note that depending on what you actually want to achieve, the `template` properties might be your best bet, for example for the [autocomplete widget](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/configuration/template).

Answer (score 0):

Some time has passed and you can attach the popup to the kendo dropdown by using the popupSetting and appendTo property:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
  [popupSettings]="{appendTo: 'component'}">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```